# How to add image to canvas?

Tags: canvas, html2canvas

When trying to apply a blur effect on an `<img>` tag, nothing is displayed on the canvas.

I am passing the `<img>`tag in a `<foreignObject>` in order to apply the blur effect.

This same technique does work for text, but not for `<img>`.

Here is my code.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="700" height="350">'+
' <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">'+
'  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">'+
   //start code
'  <div id="custom_image_box" class="col-xs-12 edit_div" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">'+
'   <div id="added_background_0" class="ui-widget-content draggable resizable ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; -webkit-filter: blur(2px);">'+
'    <img id="image_0" class="image_resize" src="http://localhost/image_designer/htdocs/assets/upload_image/1450334949.jpg" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;">'+
'    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip" "="" style="display: none;">'+
'    </div>'+
'    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip" style="display: none;">'+
'    </div>'+
'    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip" style="display: none;">'+
'    </div>'+
'    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip" style="display: none;">'+
'    </div>'+
'   </div>'+
'  </div>'+
  //end code
'  </div>'+
' </foreignObject>'+
'</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8'
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="700" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: What error do you get? You've to know that drawing an svg on IE<Edge and a `<foreignObject>` on Safari 9 does taint the canvas. html2canvas won't render the canvas element in these cases.

Comment: Its giving blank at console.

Comment: This is not an error... What is the expected result and what is the actual result? Also, if you do use html2canvas, please show us your code. A live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be great too so we can see what's going on.

Comment: When I use blur effect on text so it will reflect on canvas.but when i use effect on image then no effect show on image. I want to when i use any type of HTML 5 effect on div so it will show in canvas.

Answer (score 0):

**First,**

In order to display a `<foreignObject>` in an `<img>` tag correctly, you have to use perfectly written HTML. You forgot to close the `<img/>` tag, hence nothing was displayed. <sub>There were also some strange `"=""` attribute on the `#nwgrip` div)</sub>

To avoid such problem, the best way is to use the DOM, and to call `new XMLSerializer.serializeToString(yourDOMElement)`. This way, the browser will have done the parsing already, and your markup will be cleaned up.

<sub>Cleaned up code, where an empty image is displayed, blurred :</sub>

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="700" height="350">' +
  '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
   '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
    '<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">' +
     '<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; -webkit-filter: blur(2px); filter: blur(2px);">' +
      // added some text to show the blur effect does work
      'some text'+
      '<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1alt1303g9zpemd/UFBxY.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>' +
     '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
   '</div>' +
  '</foreignObject>' +
 '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8'
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
img.src = url;
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="700" height="350"></canvas>
```

---

**Second,**

You can't load any external data from an `<img>` tag. So in your case, it means that the `<img>` resource you want to display won't be loaded.

A solution, for this is to first convert the image to its dataURL version, then set your img tag's `src` to the wanted dataURL :

```js
var srcToDataURL = function(src, callback) {
  var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    callback(ctx.canvas.toDataURL());
  }
  img.src = src;
};

var src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1alt1303g9zpemd/UFBxY.png";

srcToDataURL(src, function(imgData) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="700" height="350">' +
    '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
    '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
    '<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">' +
    '<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; -webkit-filter: blur(2px); filter: blur(2px);">' +
    '<img src="'+  imgData + '" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</foreignObject>' +
    '</svg>';

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  var img = new Image();
  var svg = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8'
  });
  var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
  img.src = url;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="700" height="350"></canvas>
```

---

**Third,** 
IE<Edge and Safari 9 (latest) don't support the drawing of `<foreignObject>` onto the canvas, and will taint it. html2canvas won't be able to snap your canvas anymore.

If you have to support these browsers, a better approach would be to use a library like [StackBlur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html) to directly blur your images onto a canvas.

---

And as a side note, you don't need to use the Blob constructor to append your svg to a canvas, the dataURI way works in more browsers, with less known bugs :

```js
var srcToDataURL = function(src, callback) {
  var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    callback(ctx.canvas.toDataURL());
  }
  img.src = src;
};

var src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1alt1303g9zpemd/UFBxY.png";

srcToDataURL(src, function(imgData) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="700" height="350">' +
    '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
    '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
    '<div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">' +
    '<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; -webkit-filter: blur(2px); filter: blur(2px);">' +
    '<img src="'+  imgData + '" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</foreignObject>' +
    '</svg>';

  var img = new Image();
  var url = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(data);

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
  img.src = url;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="700" height="350"></canvas>
```